# Token Authentication returning 403 (Axios + Django Rest Framework)

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, token

I've been trying to fix this for a few hours now, please help me if you can.

When I try to make `get` requests w/ axios in my React app to my DRF Rest API it returns 403.

App.js:

```
      axios
        .get(API_POSTS, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Token 27dbb4dd8299792c8c52022f829da4ecec22f437`
          }
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log("Success");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    # 3rd-party apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'corsheaders',
    # Local
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
]

# Rest Framework


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
    ],
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

SITE_ID = 1

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer',
}
```

I have a `posts` endpoint that only authenticated users can see.

After logging in from within my React APP this token was generated. (using plain text for now because I'm testing)

So, when I try to make a get request with it, it returns the following error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

Why is this happening? 
Do I need to send any more information via the Header? I have read other questions and the documentation but can't find an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to check if your API works properly using something like postman ?

Comment: Hello. Yes I have, it works fine with both Postman and the built-in browsable API from the Django Rest Framework. Edit: It gives me 403 with Postman as well.

Comment: If the error comes on postman too its because the issue is with the API and not the react app.

Comment: Do you have any idea of what the error might be?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with Django hope you get an answer soon.

Comment: No problems! I managed to find a solution and posted the answer. Thank you for suggesting the Postman debugging though, it helped me.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I managed to find out what was wrong. I had to allow `TokenAuthentication` in my app.

So what I did was:

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
   'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
   )
}
```

views.py

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

After that it worked just fine.

Hope it helps everybody.