# "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."

Tags: django-rest-framework, permissions, postman

[image]

```py
    class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = ProductInfo.objects.all().order_by('-id')
       serializer_class = ProductSerializer
       permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
       authentication_classes = []
       filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
       search_fields = ['title','code','owner__username']
```

hi guys! I try to get my product list using DRF and postman... I tried several times to do it but I got an error like I said.. my `authentication_classes` is default `TokenAuthentication` and I have permission class.. this error is for my permissions
PLZ help me. thank you

[image]

I think I need to do something here.

Comment: Can you post the relevant DRF code please?

Comment: sure. I added...

Comment: Did you see this post? It seems similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151021/token-authentication-returning-403-axios-django-rest-framework. It looks like the `TokenAuthentication` authentication_class was explicitly set even though it was the `authentication_classes` default. You could give it a try.

Comment: thanks for your answer but now I get  "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Comment: Can you please post the code for how you are sending the token?

Comment: I posted something in postman

Comment: You should be providing the token in the second screenshot like you did the first screenshot now that you made the change to your viewset. I believe everything is working now, you simply need to include the token in your request.

Comment: I included my Token in the request by setting in in the header and Authorization. but i get an error like last time

Comment: Hmm well I don't know, sorry. All I can say is make sure "Authorization" is selected in Postman and ensure the token is written in the correct format according to Django rest framework docs i.e. "Token 0390a72cadc....". Otherwise everything looks good as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `Authorization` in the header with the `Token` keyword, like

```
Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Answer (score -1):

Fixed mine. You need to make sure you are using `permission_classes = ()` not `permissions_classes = ()`.

Comment: But they’re clearly using `permission_classes` in the OP, so it’s not clear how this solves the question asked.